# Flex - Mobile Project on Eclipse Plugin

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I wanted to develop a flex based mobile project. I have Eclipse plugin for Adobe Flash Builder. But I cannot see any option in the "Create Project" list for Mobile project.

Any options available ?

PS : I have seen Mobile Project is available in Flash Builder Standalone version, but I wanted it in eclipse plugin.

Comment: Which version of Flash Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Flash Builder 4.5 has the mobile project.  However, not to worry if you can't get 4.5, you can always use an automated process to do it.  Lucky for you, I've [blogged about it](http://www.michelboudreau.com/2010/08/15/flex-on-android/) and provided the files to build it automatically.

Comment: Would you mind at least summarizing the blog page here? If the link ever breaks, your answer loses quite a bit of context.

Comment: Tim, summarizing the blog page without re-writing it altogether is not really feasible.  A summary won't give much context either.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder 4.5 plug-in for eclipse. You need to upgrade your flash builder to 4.5.